# HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError in Users#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have the following three models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :associations
  has_many :pharmacies, :through => :accociations 
end

class Associations < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :pharmacy
end

class Pharmacy < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :associations
  has_many :users, :through => :accociations
end
```

When I open the `users#show` action I get the following error:

> ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError in Users#show
>
> Showing /Users/fanboy/Sites/ndt_app_v6/app/views/users/show.html.erb where line #14 raised:
>
> > Could not find the association :accociations in model User
>
> Extracted source (around line #14):
>
> ```
> 11:   <div class="span8">
> 12:     <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
> 13:       <%= f.label :pharmacy_ids, "Pharmacies" %><br />
> 14:       <%= f.collection_select :pharmacy_ids, Pharmacy.order(:name), :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true} %>
> 15:     <% end %>
> 16:   </div>
> 17: </div>
> ```

Basically I would like to allow Users to associate themselves with a Pharmacy. Instead I get the error above, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please try to strip out the irrelevant code when you post questions. There is absolutely no reason to post anything about your controllers or routes here, and nobody wants to dredge through a thousand lines of code to find the one or two relevant lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment is way off, and the linked documentation has nothing to do with your problem.

The problem with your code is that you have a brutally obvious typo in several places. Your association is called `associations`, but your `:through` uses `accociations`.

Associations vs A**CC**ociations.

Rails is telling you exactly what the error is:

```
Could not find the association :accociations in model User
```

The reason your linked documentation fixed your problem is that you probably spelled the new association name correctly. It's pretty important that you spell things correctly when programming, and such an obvious typo should really leap out at you.